# Can your iPhone app be notified of new notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios

If your iPhone app is running is there a way to let the app know when a new notification comes in?

Normally the notification window pops up on the top then goes away, but that is handled by the system.  Is there a call made to the app that is currently running?

While my app is running I would like to keep track of new notifications.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Not all the notifications, just the notifications your app is registered for. One of the best tutorials in this topic: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a call made to the AppDelegate

`-didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
-(void)application: (UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}
```

Comment: is this just for notifications generated by the app or for all notifications regardless of origin?

Comment: No, for local notifications you need to implement `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`